# High CPU Usage in Windows 7

Tags: windows, cpu, process

My computer sometimes runs at 100% CPU and gets real slow. When I start task manager to see which process is causing it, there is a process named "1347142115.exe" and it uses 99% of the CPU. When I end it, CPU usage goes back to normal. I don't know which application causes this process so I can't uninstall it. Is this a virus? How do I get rid of it? Is a format necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Download [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free/) and [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download). Check you system for malware and viruses.  Download also [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) Task Manager it gives you more information about the processes running on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the Windows 7 start icon in the bottom left corner of your screen.
   Windows 7 start logo
2. Type MSCONFIG in the search box and then either press enter on your keyboard or double-click on the MSCONFIG program that appears in the search results.

   - disable application in startup tab
   - Have a look in Command line then locate virus and delete it
     [image: Msconfig]